# Check if input is empty

Tags: python, function, variables, input

```
from math import sin, pi

def I1(n, a, b):
    try:
        h = (b-a)/n
        summe = 0
        if a < b:
            for k in range(0, n-1):
                summe += sin(a+(k + 0.5)* h)
                summe *= pi/n
            print("Das Integral von",a ,"bis", b,"entspricht ungefähr:" , summe)
        else: print("Beachte, die untere Grenze 'a' sollte kleiner als die\
obere Grenze 'b'")
    except TypeError:
        h = 1000
        a = 0
        b = pi
```

My question is how to check in Def I1(n, a, b) if the given three variables are emtpy. Can some one help? I have tried try/except and "if n is None and a is None and b is None".

Comment: Why is your code in a picture? Why isn't it in text in your question?

Comment: I had some formating errors....

Comment: Paste it in, select it and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Check if all or at least one is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staying as true to what you provided as I can, I end up with this.

```
from math import sin, pi


def I1(n, a, b):
    if n is None and a is None and b is None:
        h = 1000
        a = 0
        b = pi
        n =  # ?
    else:
        h = (b - a) / n
    summe = 0
    if a < b:
        for k in range(0, n - 1):
            summe += sin(a + (k + 0.5) * h)
            summe *= pi / n
        print("Das Integral von", a, "bis", b, "entspricht ungefähr:", summe)
    else:
        print("Beachte, die untere Grenze 'a' sollte kleiner als die obere",
            "Grenze 'b'")
```

That's assuming you want to set the defaults if all of the arguments are None. I'm not sure that condition is what you're looking for, however. If I had to guess your intent, I would replace the condition with something like this.

```
if n is None:
    n = 1000
if a is None:
    a = 0
if b is None:
    b = pi
h = (b - a) / n
```

Or if you want to make sure they're numbers and not just not None, you could do something like this.

```
if not isinstance(n, int) and not isinstance(n, float):
    n = 1000
if not isinstance(a, int) and not isinstance(a, float):
    a = 0
if not isinstance(b, int) and not isinstance(b, float):
    b = pi
h = (b - a) / n
```